# Mail Server saslauthd pam_authenticate failed

Tags: email, postfix, sasl

Every month/3 weeks, my Mail server fails to send any new mails, and each time i find the below error log,

```
Jun 22 23:10:18 myserver saslauthd[3967]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Memory buffer error
Jun 22 23:10:18 myserver saslauthd[3971]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Memory buffer error
Jun 22 23:10:19 myserver saslauthd[3972]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Memory buffer error
Jun 22 23:10:19 myserver saslauthd[3968]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Memory buffer error
Jun 22 23:10:20 myserver saslauthd[3969]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Memory buffer error
Jun 22 23:10:20 myserver saslauthd[3967]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Memory buffer error
Jun 22 23:10:21 myserver saslauthd[3971]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Memory buffer error
Jun 22 23:10:21 myserver saslauthd[3972]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Memory buffer error
Jun 22 23:10:22 myserver saslauthd[3971]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Memory buffer error
```

Every time i have to restart myserver to work normally again

I also always find the below repetitive error log from unknown IPs (i am not sure if it is related or not):

```
Jun 21 06:48:43 myserver sshd[1687]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=************  user=root
Jun 21 06:48:45 myserver sshd[1708]: Failed password for root from ######## port 60021 ssh2
Jun 21 06:48:47 myserver sshd[1708]: Failed password for root from ######## port 60021 ssh2
Jun 21 06:48:47 myserver sshd[1708]: Received disconnect from #######: 11:  [preauth]
Jun 21 06:48:47 myserver sshd[1708]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=************  user=root
Jun 21 06:48:47 myserver sshd[1730]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=************  user=root
Jun 21 06:48:48 myserver sshd[1732]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=============  user=root
Jun 21 06:48:48 myserver sshd[1730]: Failed password for root from ************ port 60094 ssh2
Jun 21 06:48:50 myserver sshd[1732]: Failed password for root from ============ port 40613 ssh2
Jun 21 06:48:50 myserver sshd[1730]: Failed password for root from ************ port 60094 ssh2
Jun 21 06:48:50 myserver sshd[1734]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=************  user=root
Jun 21 06:48:52 myserver sshd[1736]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=************  user=root
Jun 21 06:48:52 myserver sshd[1732]: Failed password for root from ============ port 40613 ssh2
Jun 21 06:48:52 myserver sshd[1730]: Failed password for root from ************ port 60094 ssh2
Jun 21 06:48:52 myserver sshd[1730]: Received disconnect from ***********: 11:  [preauth]
Jun 21 06:48:52 myserver sshd[1730]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=***********  user=root
Jun 21 06:48:52 myserver sshd[1734]: Failed password for root from ######## port 47803 ssh2
Jun 21 06:48:54 myserver sshd[1736]: Failed password for root from ######## port 55371 ssh2
Jun 21 06:48:54 myserver sshd[1732]: Failed password for root from ============ port 40613 ssh2
```

Answer (score 0):

It writes it -- `failed: Memory buffer error`. You are running out of physical memory, disk space, swap or whatever, and pam doesn't handle it well. Which one can't be more evaluated from this log.

Check what is eating too much memory before reboot or upgrade your hardware.